Boa giving me a cryptic error, how to decipher?
I've sent a transaction on a contract using titanoboa, and I received an error that looks like this:
boa.contracts.base_evm_contract.BoaError: 
========================================================================
[E] [63933] pool.supply(asset = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48", amount = 2000000000000000000000, onBehalfOf = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", referralCode = 0) <51>
    [E] [58856] Unknown contract 0xeF434E4573b90b6ECd4a00f4888381e4D0CC5Ccd.0x617ba037
        [E] [54935] Unknown contract 0x2b22E425C1322fbA0DbF17bb1dA25d71811EE7ba.0x1913f161
            [7468] Unknown contract 0x72E95b8931767C79bA4EeE721354d6E99a61D004.0xb1bf962d
                [2419] Unknown contract 0xaC725CB59D16C81061BDeA61041a8A5e73DA9EC6.0xb1bf962d
            [7424] Unknown contract 0x98C23E9d8f34FEFb1B7BD6a91B7FF122F4e16F5c.0xb1bf962d
                [2375] Unknown contract 0x7EfFD7b47Bfd17e52fB7559d3f924201b9DbfF3d.0xb1bf962d

How do I tell what the error is? This is very cryptic. This is calling the supply function on an aave v3 contract.

If you look at the top line:
[E] [63933] pool.supply(asset = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48", amount = 2000000000000000000000, onBehalfOf = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", referralCode = 0) <51>

The section with the <> contains the error that the contract gave you. In this instance, the literal error you got was 51. This is because AaveV3 contracts give you error codes as opposed to error text.
You can read more about the 51 error code from AaveV3 here
